# Jsoup downloading error. Says must be logged in, but there's no login

Tags: web-crawler, jsoup

Specs:  My company's server runs Jsoup to download pdfs based on links I provide it

I sometimes run into this problem where a website has a document (pdf or otherwise) which I can download normally from my browser, but through my scraping software it returns an error such as this

> Something went wrong. Oh no! Something is not right! Try to log in again. If you continue to see this error, please contact us at support@agendapal.com Error description: MessageInvalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed. TargetSiteVoid CreateThis(System.String, Boolean, System.UriKind) StackTrace at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind) at SWPalInc.WebHost.Controllers.DController.F(String u, String n) at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.b__5() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0() at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) DataSystem.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal InnerException SourceSystem Click here and try to login again

I received that error when I try to extract the pdf from a link such as this using my company server https://meetings.municode.com/d/f?u=https://agendapalncus.blob.core.windows.net/paonia-pubu/MEET-Agenda-e11f135d48564ad983c6c46949e34894.pdf&n=Agenda-Regular%20Town%20Board%20Meeting-February%2026,%202019%206.30%20PM.pdf

I've tried using a proxy server but I get the same issue when I crawl it.  Anyone know a solution to this issue or seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to parse this URL with Jsoup it throws

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type.
Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml.
```

so it seems like it's throwing proper, explicit exception. Try catching and handling this exception. That's how I would do it in Java:

```
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        (...)
    } catch (UnsupportedMimeTypeException ex) {
        // handle exception here
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a good idea.  I'm not developing that portion of the code but I should do what you are doing and just run Jsoup on my own.  Thanks